# How to load JSON data in Django and create a model

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework, backend

I'm trying to load json data file and create Player class with given json data file.
I looked up documentation on Django website and some posts on stack overflow but couldn't figure out how to do it.
When I tried creating a class method of create() on models.py, I kept getting no table exists error.
Can anyone help me figure it out?? thank you in advance

For models.py I have player class

```
    class Player(models.Model):

    pos = models.CharField(max_length=2, default="")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default="")

    age = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    posRank = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    throwAtt = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    throwYd = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    throwTD = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    interception = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    rushAtt = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    rushYd = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    rushTD = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    rushAvgYd = models.FloatField()

    target = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    rec = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    recYd = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    recAvgYd = models.FloatField()
    recTD = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    totalTD = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    fumble = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    fpts = models.FloatField(null=True)
    ppr = models.FloatField()
    totGames = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

and for serializers.py
I have player serializer written as below

```
    class PlayerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:

        model = Player
        fields = ('name', 'pos', 'age', 'posRank', 'throwAtt', 'throwYds', 'throwTD',
                  'interception', 'rushAtt', 'rushYd', 'rushTD', 'rushAvgYd', 'target',
                  'rec', 'recYd', 'recAvgYd', 'recTD' 'totalTD', 'fumble', 'fpts', 'ppr', 'totGames')


and inside views.py i have this class

class PlayerView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    players = Player.objects.all()
    serializer = PlayerSerializer(players, many=True)

    def get(self, request):
        output = json.load('api/NewNFLdata.json')
        for player in output:
            newPlayer = Player(pos=player["FantPos"],
                               name=player["Player"],
                               age=player["Age"],
                               posRank=player["PosRank"],
                               throwAtt=player["Att"],
                               throwYd=player["Yds"],
                               throwTD=player["TD"],
                               interception=player["Int"],
                               rushAtt=player["Att.1"],
                               rushYd=player["Yds.1"],
                               rushTD=player["TD.1"],
                               rushAvgYd=player["Y/A"],
                               target=player["Tgt"],
                               rec=player["Rec"],
                               recYd=player["Yds.2"],
                               recAvgYd=player["Y/R"],
                               recTD=player["TD.2"],
                               totalTD=player["TD.3"],
                               fumble=player["Fmb"],
                               fpts=player["FantPt"],
                               ppr=player["PPR"],
                               totGames=player["G"]
                               )
            newPlayer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I tried to do it by my own by looking up stack overflow
but couldn't find a way to load json data into model

Comment: Those are called fixtures, you don't need to implement it from scratch, search `Django` documentation for `Fixure`

Comment: When i try to load the fixture, Do I have to have a same key value as a fields defined in serializer class?

Comment: Do you want to load json data only once or do you need to import functionality in your app so that users will be able to load data by importing json files?

Comment: @JaewooCho see [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/initial-data/#:~:text=A%20fixture%20is%20a%20collection,the%20manage.py%20dumpdata%20command.)

Comment: Fixtures have a fixed structure, study it then apply it, and your answer is no, fixtures are model related, not serializer related (django, not DRF)

Comment: @Deniz I just wanna load it once so I can access that data on app

Comment: @AhmedI.Elsayed Ye I think I know how to load the fixture. but the problem is how I could change the current json data into fixture format... Is there any way I can change the format ??

Comment: Automate it, you're a developer

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at fixtures:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/initial-data/

If you can tweak your JSON files to the appropriate format, you'll get the benefits of Django's fixtures loading process, which includes field validation that you won't have to write. Good luck!

Comment: Ye I looked at that too. I tried loading the data but it seems like it's not working for some reason..

Comment: Do I have to have a same key value as a fields defined in serializer class?

Comment: What output do you get when you run the `loaddata` command?

Comment: I get no such table error, but I think I figured out how to load json data as fixture. My problem is that How can I tweak my JSON file to the appropriate format.